# Caching videos in Android Webview

Tags: android, caching, video, amazon-s3, webview

I have a playlist WebApp that plays videos from s3. I added the cache-control metadata in s3 which seems to cache videos on my computer's chrome. But it does not cache videos in the Android Webview on my Tablet. Here are the webview settings :

```
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

Is there anything else I should be doing?